# Lock background while DIV overlay is on

Tags: html, overlay

Hi all  i am a noob in web programming.
Can anyone help me to create a DIV overlay which when executed should automatically disable click on other parts of web page (Like when we click send message on face book we can't click on other parts).....i hope my question is clear...thanks

Comment: Adding some details of what you've tried and what code you are working with would improve your question. (Also, it sounds like you are talking about a modal overlay if that helps you search).

Answer (score 5):

You could simply do this with a single `div`

**CSS**

```
#overlay {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:100000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Just show and hide the div to enable and disable the content on the page. You could also `absolute` position the div over other `relative` areas to disable only certain areas.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dX3qb/

Comment: I'll add that the toggle button should be positioned above (`z-index:100001;`) the overlay. I remember being a noob and couldn't un-toggle the overlay :D